# The name "X" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and variables. Column names are not permitted

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server.  I am getting an error from an SQL Insert statement:

```
The name "InvalidAwps" is not permitted in this context. Valid
expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts)
variables. Column names are not permitted.
```

This is the Insert SQL that produces that error:

```
Insert Into [PlanFinder].[ReportLinks]
(TypeOfReport, Links) Values (InvalidAwps, \\uafc.com\ReportLinks\InvalidAwps);
```

And here is the table definition:

```
Create Table [PlanFinder].[ReportLinks]
(
  [TypeOfReport]      Char (11)             Not Null,
  [Links]             Money                 Null,
  Constraint pk_TypeOfReport Primary Key Clustered (TypeOfReport)
)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need string delimiters

```
Insert Into [PlanFinder].[ReportLinks]
(TypeOfReport, Links) Values ('InvalidAwps', '\\uafc.com\ReportLinks\InvalidAwps')
```

However, then you'll get errors inserting the string `\\uafc.com\ReportLinks\InvalidAwps` into a `money` column...

or are `\\\InvalidAwps`,`\\\Missing` meant to be symbols of some kind?

Comment: I was about to ask about that.  Is this a link to a file or something?

Comment: @JNK: some info it could have been removed too, because it was not "code layout"!

Comment: thats actually the path of the report. thanks i forgot the inverted commas.

Answer (score 5):

Try putting `InvalidAwps` in single quotes:

```
Insert Into [PlanFinder].[ReportLinks] (TypeOfReport, Links) 
Values ('InvalidAwps', '\uafc.com\ReportLinks\InvalidAwps')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Reproduce this error in SQL Server.**

Create a string column and use Double quotes to insert values instead of single quotes:

```
create table yar (id VARCHAR(50));
insert into yar values("yarrrr");
```

Causes error:

```
Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The name "yarrrr" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are 
constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names 
are not permitted.
```

Fix it by using single quotes like this:

```
create table yar (id VARCHAR(50));
insert into yar values('yarrrr');
```

Prints:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
```